# Yii 2.0 - deny "index.php" access

Tags: .htaccess, yii2

I am learning Yii 2.0 Framework. I configured urlManager like this:

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                '' => 'site',
            ],
        ],
```

SiteController only one action - actionIndex (default one). What I want is only 'mydomain.com' being accessible (with all other requests resulting in 404 error). But right now I can call 'site/index' action with numerous ways:

- mydomain.com
- mydomain.com/site/index
- mydomain.com/index.php
- mydomain.com/index.php/site/index
- mydomain.com/index.php?r=site/index

... and so on. My .htaccess file is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

# if request dosn't start with web add it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(web)
RewriteRule (.*) $1

# if file or directory dosn't exists go to /web/index.php 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

So how can I restrict all of those and make my app work ONLY with routes directly specified in urlManager rules?

---

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the top of your rules (right below "RewriteEngine On")

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.php
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R=404]
```